# Sidenav not working window.innerWidth - Angular 16.0.2

Tags: angular, sidenav

I'm using Angular 16.0.2, I try that when I click the start button of my sidenav, it expands to the right, resizing the area. but it does not work

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

the html file, I just want to know why it doesn't work, that is, it doesn't push the area to the left, it just sits on top

**Sidenav.component.html**

```
 <div class="sidenav" [ngClass]="collapsed ? 'sidenav-collapsed' : ''">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <button class="logo" (click)="toggleCollapse()">T</button>
    <div class="logo-text" @fadeInOut *ngIf="collapsed">ThesisWApp</div>
    <button class="btn-close" @rotate *ngIf="collapsed" (click)="closeSidenav()">
      <i class="fal fa-times close-icon"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <ul class="sidenav-nav">
    <li class="sidenav-nav-item" *ngFor="let data of navData">
      <a class="sidenav-nav-link" [routerLink]="[data.routeLink]"
        routerLinkActive="active"
        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
      >
        <i class="sidenav-link-icon" [class]="data.icon"></i>
        <span class="sidenav-link-text" @fadeInOut *ngIf="collapsed">
          {{data.label}}
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Sidenav.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { navbarData } from './nav-data';
import { animate, keyframes, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

interface SideNavToggle{
  screenWidth: number;
  collapsed: boolean
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut',[
      transition(':enter',[
        style({opacity:0}),
        animate('350ms',
        style({opacity:1})
        )
      ]),
      transition(':leave',[
        style({opacity:1}),
        animate('350ms',
        style({opacity:0})
        )
      ])
    ]),
    trigger('rotate', [
      transition(':enter', [
        animate('1000ms', 
          keyframes([
            style({transform: 'rotate(0deg)', offset: '0'}),
            style({transform: 'rotate(2turn)', offset: '1'})
          ])
        )
      ])
    ])
  ]
})

export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() onToggleSideNav: EventEmitter<SideNavToggle> = new EventEmitter();
  collapsed = false;
  screenWidth = 0;
  navData = navbarData;

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  //onResize(event: any){
  onWindowResize(){
    this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if (this.screenWidth <= 768){
      this.collapsed = false;
      this.onToggleSideNav.emit({collapsed: this.collapsed, screenWidth: this.screenWidth});
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

  toggleCollapse(): void {
    this.collapsed = !this.collapsed;
    this.onToggleSideNav.emit({collapsed: this.collapsed, screenWidth: this.screenWidth});
  }

  closeSidenav(): void {
    this.collapsed = false;
    this.onToggleSideNav.emit({collapsed: this.collapsed, screenWidth: this.screenWidth});
  }

}
```

with this instruction "window.innerWidth ", it should work

[image]

Comment: please post more code or post a stackblitz link. I need more info to help

Comment: update the post, the idea is to create a sidenav that when you click on the start button, it expands, but when doing so it pushes the work area and does not remain below

Comment: please provide the full component

Comment: there is the component, if you see I don't see any problem, in the ts, navbarData is imported, where are the menu icons, so why doesn't it work? Could it be because in Angular 16.0.2 it is done differently?

Comment: It seems, that the container component of the sidebar (where the sidebar component is hosted) hast applied a position: absolute or fixed on it. If you want to have a sidebar which pushes the main content, put the sidebar and the main content in a flex container and animate the margin-left property (0% to -100%) of the sidebar component

Comment: You usually want to do it like this: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-welcome-app-wpzdrp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, it still doesn't work for me, if I give you the example code that I uploaded to github, would you see it?